# Adding react to static html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, webstorm

I would like to add a React component in one of the divs from a static HTML page. I'm doing so instead of converting the entire page into React since I only need React for few parts of my web page. I followed the instructions on https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html. And my questions are:

1. Is it okay to do that, or is it rather recommended that I implement my website entirely in React?
2. I did what the aforementioned page told me, but the section I used React did not get implemented when I displayed it on my browser (my IDE is WebStorm). Is there a specific script (like yarn start when using React framework) that I have to run in order to compile?

Comment: Would you be able to share you code? Need to see how you have implemented your component.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Checkout this minimal example. You need to include 3 scripts

> - react.development.js (the react lib)
> - react-dom.development.js (react lib to interact with dom)
> - babel.min.js (converts react JSX into browser compatible JS)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        
        <!-- Don't use this in production: -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type="text/babel">
          function HelloWorld(props){
            return <h1>{`Hello, world! ${props.name}`}</h1>;
          }
          ReactDOM.render(
            <HelloWorld name="James"/>,
            document.getElementById('root')
          );
    
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**Note: this is a great way to try React but it's not suitable for production.
  It slowly compiles JSX with Babel in the browser and uses a large development build of React.**

- Read this section for a production-ready setup with JSX:
  https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-jsx-to-a-project
- In a larger project, you can use an integrated toolchain that
  includes JSX instead:
  https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html
- You can also use React without JSX, in which case you can remove
  Babel:   https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html

SOURCE : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/master/static/html/single-file-example.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it's ok. No, your entire website doesn't need to use React.
2. It should work as described in the tutorial you linked, you don't need to compile anything. The scripts invoked by yarn or npm in frontend projects usually bundle javascript modules together and transpile (we don't call it compiling since there is no machine code as output) from a modern version of EcmaScript into an older, established version of EcmaScript that is understood by most browsers. But for your small example, none of this really matters. In order to identify why your code doesn't work, it would be helpful to see it.

Comment: Would be helpful to include some example of the process for users to refer to.